# File upload using ASP.NET and HTML form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to create the functionality that allows to upload the image and store it into the db.
I have this input field in my HTML form:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddTR", "TestCell", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="modal" id="NewTRModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" style="width:1250px;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="box5">
        <div>
          <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
            Upload Image1
          </label>
          <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="image1"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary button button4"> Submit</button>
          <button type="button" id="btnHideModal" class="btn btn-primary button button4">Hide</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

And I am trying to get the file in my controller through

```
IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files["image1"];
```

However, for some reasons after I am clicking submit button the `Request.Form.Files` is empty.

I will appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web browsers will upload files properly only when the HTML form
element defines an `enctype` value of `multipart/form-data`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddTR", "TestCell", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ...
    <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="image1"/>
    ...
}
```

Without the `enctype` attribute, the browser will transmit only the name of the file and not its content.

Then in the controller action method you can use the same name as defined in the `<input>` tag as a parameter:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddTR(HttpPostedFileBase image1)
{
    if (image1 != null && image1.ContentLength > 0)   
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"~/"), Path.GetFileName(image1.FileName));
        image1.SaveAs(path);
    }
    ...
}
```

---

**In case you are using ASP.NET Core (what you didn't mention in the question) you can define the `enctype` attribute and than use:**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddTR()
{
    IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files["image1"]; 
    ....
}
```